# Python Gloabal Variables Behaving Differently in Windows and Linux

Tags: python, linux, windows

I have some Python 2.7 code I'm porting from Linux to Windows, many parts of it I did not write. It's throwing errors when I run it on Windows that it never complained about in Linux and I was hoping someone would be able to point me in the direction required to fix them.

At the start of the program, it calls a library that creates and populates a global list. It then spawns a couple of new processes. These processes eventually make calls to the first library that refer to the global list. The code looks something like

```
configList = {}

def load_config(fname):
  global configList
  configList['container'] = 'x'
  ...


def get_container():
  container = configList['container']
  return container
```

The code works fine in Linux, but throws a number of errors in Windows relating to the global list not being filled out. I've ran into some things online that say multiple processes won't have access to the same global variables, but it strikes me as odd that this would not be the case in Linux.

Comment: It would help to provide the errors and the lines that are throwing them.

Comment: Did you follow the [guidelines in the multiprocessing documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-programming)? In particular, did you make `__main__` import-safe?

Comment: Windows doesn't have `fork`. This causes most of the multiprocessing weirdness on Windows.

Comment: You don't need the `global` keyword there since you are not rebinding `configList`

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks for the link. I switched the code around to pass the desired variables.